# NodeJS - Child node process?

Tags: node.js

I'm using NodeJS to run a socket server (using socket.io). When a client connects, I want am opening and running a module which does a bunch of stuff. Even though I am careful to try and catch as much as possible, when this module throws an error, it obviously takes down the entire socket server with it.

Is there a way I can separate the two so if the connected clients module script fails, it doesn't necessarily take down the entire server?

I'm assuming this is what child process is for, but the documentation doesn't mention starting other node instances.

I'd obviously need to kill the process if the client disconnected too.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm assuming these modules you're talking about are JS code. If so, you might want to try the [vm module](http://nodejs.org/docs/v0.4.8/api/vm.html). This lets you run code in a separate context, and also gives you the ability to do a `try / catch` around execution of the specific code.

You can run node as a separate process and watch the data go by using [spawn](http://nodejs.org/docs/v0.4.8/api/child_processes.html#child_process.spawn), then watch the stderr/stdout/exit events to track any progress. Then [kill](http://nodejs.org/docs/v0.4.8/api/child_processes.html#child.kill) can be used to kill the process if the client disconnects. You're going to have to map clients and spawned processes though so their disconnect event will trigger the process close properly.

Finally the [uncaughtException](http://nodejs.org/docs/v0.4.8/api/process.html#event_uncaughtException_) event can be used as a "catch-all" for any missed exceptions, making it so that the server doesn't get completely killed (signals are a bit of an exception of course).

Answer (score 1):

As the other poster noted, you could leverage the 'vm' module, but as you might be able to tell from the rest of the response, doing so adds significant complexity.

Also, from the 'vm' doc:

```
Note that running untrusted code is a tricky business requiring great care. 
To prevent accidental global variable leakage, vm.runInNewContext is quite 
useful, but safely running untrusted code requires a separate process.
```

While I'm sure you could run a new nodejs instance in a child process, the best practice here is to understand where your application can and will fail, and then program defensively to handle all possible error conditions.

If some part of your code "take(s) down the entire ... server", then you really to understand why this occurred and solve that problem rather than rely on another process to shield you from the work required to design and build a production-quality service.